# Pandas concat similar DataFrames and Series

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have a list of Dataframes, all with the same columns. Occaisionally, a DataFrame has only one row, and is, hence, a Series. When I try to concatenate this list with `pd.concat`, where there was a Series, it puts what I want to be the columns in the index. See below for a minimal working example.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [2]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [3]: d = {'a':np.random.randn(100), 'b':np.random.randn(100)}                                                                                                                                                         

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(d)                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [5]: thing1 = df.iloc[:10, :]                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [6]: thing1                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[6]: 
          a         b
0 -0.505268 -1.109089
1 -1.792729 -0.580566
2 -0.478042  0.410095
3 -0.758376  0.558772
4  0.112519  0.556316
5 -1.015813 -0.568148
6  1.234858 -1.062879
7 -0.455796 -0.107942
8  1.231422  0.780694
9 -1.082461 -1.809412

In [7]: thing2 = df.iloc[10,:]                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [8]: thing2                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[8]: 
a   -1.527836
b    0.653610
Name: 10, dtype: float64

In [9]: thing3 = df.iloc[11:, :]                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [10]: thing3                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[10]: 
           a         b
11 -1.247939 -0.694491
12  1.359737  0.625284
13 -0.491533 -0.230665
14  1.360465  0.472451
15  0.691532 -1.822708
16  0.938316  1.310101
17  0.485776 -0.313206
18  1.398189 -0.232446
19 -0.626278  0.714052
20 -1.292272 -1.299580
21 -1.521746 -1.615611
22  1.464332  2.839602
23  0.707370 -0.162056
24 -1.825903  0.000278
25  0.917284 -0.094716
26 -0.239839  0.132572
27 -0.463240 -0.805458
28  1.174125  0.131057
29  0.183503  0.328603
30  0.045839 -0.244965
31  0.449265  0.642082
32  2.381600 -0.417044
33  0.276217 -0.257426
34  0.755067  0.012898
35  0.130339 -0.094300
36 -1.643097  0.038982
37  0.895719  0.789494
38  0.701480 -0.668440
39 -0.201400  1.441928
40 -2.018043 -0.106764
..       ...       ...
70  0.971799  0.298164
71  1.307070 -2.093075
72 -1.049177  2.183065
73 -0.469273 -0.739449
74  0.685838  2.579547
75  1.994485  0.783204
76 -0.414760 -0.285766
77 -1.005873 -0.783886
78  1.486588 -0.349575
79  1.417006 -0.676501
80  1.284611 -0.817505
81 -0.624406 -1.659931
82 -0.921061  0.424663
83 -0.645472 -0.769509
84 -1.217172 -0.943542
85 -0.184948  0.482977
86 -0.253972 -0.080682
87 -0.699122  0.368751
88  1.391163  0.042899
89 -0.075512  0.019728
90  0.449151  0.486462
91 -0.182553  0.876379
92 -0.209162  0.390093
93  0.789094  1.570251
94 -1.018724 -0.084603
95  1.109534  1.840739
96  0.774806 -0.380387
97  0.534344  1.165343
98  1.003597 -0.221899
99 -0.659863 -1.061590

[89 rows x 2 columns]

In [11]: pd.concat([thing1, thing2, thing3])                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[11]: 
           a         b         0
0  -0.505268 -1.109089       NaN
1  -1.792729 -0.580566       NaN
2  -0.478042  0.410095       NaN
3  -0.758376  0.558772       NaN
4   0.112519  0.556316       NaN
5  -1.015813 -0.568148       NaN
6   1.234858 -1.062879       NaN
7  -0.455796 -0.107942       NaN
8   1.231422  0.780694       NaN
9  -1.082461 -1.809412       NaN
a        NaN       NaN -1.527836
b        NaN       NaN  0.653610
11 -1.247939 -0.694491       NaN
12  1.359737  0.625284       NaN
13 -0.491533 -0.230665       NaN
14  1.360465  0.472451       NaN
15  0.691532 -1.822708       NaN
16  0.938316  1.310101       NaN
17  0.485776 -0.313206       NaN
18  1.398189 -0.232446       NaN
19 -0.626278  0.714052       NaN
20 -1.292272 -1.299580       NaN
21 -1.521746 -1.615611       NaN
22  1.464332  2.839602       NaN
23  0.707370 -0.162056       NaN
24 -1.825903  0.000278       NaN
25  0.917284 -0.094716       NaN
26 -0.239839  0.132572       NaN
27 -0.463240 -0.805458       NaN
28  1.174125  0.131057       NaN
..       ...       ...       ...
70  0.971799  0.298164       NaN
71  1.307070 -2.093075       NaN
72 -1.049177  2.183065       NaN
73 -0.469273 -0.739449       NaN
74  0.685838  2.579547       NaN
75  1.994485  0.783204       NaN
76 -0.414760 -0.285766       NaN
77 -1.005873 -0.783886       NaN
78  1.486588 -0.349575       NaN
79  1.417006 -0.676501       NaN
80  1.284611 -0.817505       NaN
81 -0.624406 -1.659931       NaN
82 -0.921061  0.424663       NaN
83 -0.645472 -0.769509       NaN
84 -1.217172 -0.943542       NaN
85 -0.184948  0.482977       NaN
86 -0.253972 -0.080682       NaN
87 -0.699122  0.368751       NaN
88  1.391163  0.042899       NaN
89 -0.075512  0.019728       NaN
90  0.449151  0.486462       NaN
91 -0.182553  0.876379       NaN
92 -0.209162  0.390093       NaN
93  0.789094  1.570251       NaN
94 -1.018724 -0.084603       NaN
95  1.109534  1.840739       NaN
96  0.774806 -0.380387       NaN
97  0.534344  1.165343       NaN
98  1.003597 -0.221899       NaN
99 -0.659863 -1.061590       NaN

[101 rows x 3 columns]
```

Please note that for this problem, I need to maintain the original index.

I've spent a long time investigating the documentation but can't seem to figure out my problem. Is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
thing2 = pd.DataFrame(thing2).transpose()
pd.concat([thing1, thing2, thing3])
```

In your case `transpose()` will set `Pandas Series` index as colums and then you can concate easily.
Documentation here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html